# update manager not detecting upgrade to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, update-manager

I am using ubuntu 11.10 and update manager is not showing the option to upgrade it to 12.04.
I have selected the 'Notify me of new Ubuntu version:' option to 'For any new version as suggested by some people, but still i am not getting the option to upgrade.

Screenshot of Selecting Option:
[image: Screenshot of Selecting Option]

Screen shot of update manager not detecting upgrade:
[image: Screen shot of update manager not detecting upgrade]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things that you can do:

The first is to ALT-F2 and start update manager with the command

```
update-manager -d
```

the -d should show the upgrade option (you might have to check for updates first)

The second thing you can do is to upgrade from the command line with the command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: Is there any way to get this done without the commandline option? It was showing the upgrade for me a day ago, but after a BADSIG error, it does not show now.